# Parametric equations - plotting graph

Tags: parametric

I was wondering how can one draw a graph (at least schematic) from given parametric equation, 
For example I took 
$$x=a\cos^3(t)\qquad
\text{and}\qquad 
y=a\sin^3(t).$$
Initially I tried to find solution of $x=y$.

And then where it get zero, but I was unable to plot it.

How shall I do it?

Comment: Do you mean, draw by hand? I would say that the most intuitive approach is to choose values for $t$, plug them into the two equations and then add the created point to the graph.

Comment: In this case you can try to solve for $t$ in the equation for $x$; and then plug in the result for the equation of $y$.

Comment: Yes, but when you plug it in this case you can do, but if equations were different like. X=|cos(4t)|cos(t) and y=|cos(4t)| sin(t) then how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$. I've used the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1$ to get rid of $t$. The curve is called an astroid. You can find more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).